# Solve "deadlock-like" situation with python threading and tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, deadlock

I'm having a "deadlock-like" problem, where a thread needs to wait for the main thread to close before closing, but of course that one won't close until the other one closes.
My code is analogous to this:

```
import threading
from tkinter import *

def questions_funct():
    while True:
        if input("Do you want to close?:")=="YES":
            root.destroy()
            break

root = Tk()
questions_thread = threading.Thread(target=questions_funct)
questions_thread.start()
root.mainloop()
```

From what I've tested, nothing after root.destroy executes, but stuff after root.mainloop() does. So, it's clear root.destroy() is executed successfully which is further backed up by the window closing. Of course, the console is still open, a clear indicator that something is still running.

Might be important to add that all the testing was done with print("Test") stuff, so I'm definitely not sure if what I found out is true.

I've been banging my head against the wall in search of answers. Any help?

Comment: I'd personnaly look for other way of the user telling the program to exit. I'd maybe try `from multiprocessing import Process` and try it with that.

Comment: Set `daemon=True` for your `questions_thread`. You also forgot to start the thread in your example here.

Comment: @Darkonaut: Please explain, **why** do we need `daemon=True`?

Comment: @stovfl Wish I could but I'm not into tkinter, I tested it on suspicion and it worked.

Comment: @Darkonaut: Indeed it does??

Comment: @Gogotron: Read about [Tkinter.Wm.protocol-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.protocol-method). Relevant [TopLevel Destroy not being detected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51751514/7414759)